# How to use title Animations in codename one

Tags: codenameone

Pls how do i use Title Animations in CN1 to animate pictures in src directory. I followed the developer guide which I used the sample code. When I ran the code the picture did not perform any animation. I want to modify this code to iterate the pictures in src directory so that I can have for example, img1, img2, img3. showing on the Title bar. Pls how do i go about this.

This is the code I used.

```
 Form hi = new Form("Toolbar", new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
EncodedImage placeholder =
EncodedImage.createFromImage(Image.createImage(hi.getWidth(),
hi.getWidth() / 5, 0xffff0000), true);
URLImage background = URLImage.createToStorage(placeholder, "400px-  AGameOfThrones.jpg","http://awoiaf.westeros.org/images/thumb/9/93/AGameOfThrones.jpg/400px-AGameOfThrones.jpg");
background.fetch();
Style stitle = hi.getToolbar().getTitleComponent().getUnselectedStyle();
stitle.setBgImage(background);
stitle.setBackgroundType(Style.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_SCALED_FILL);
stitle.setPaddingUnit(Style.UNIT_TYPE_DIPS, Style.UNIT_TYPE_DIPS,
Style.UNIT_TYPE_DIPS, Style.UNIT_TYPE_DIPS);
stitle.setPaddingTop(15);
     SpanButton credit = new SpanButton("This excerpt is from A Wiki Of Ice             AndFire. Please check it out by clicking here!");
credit.addActionListener((e) ->         Display.getInstance().execute("http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/A_Game_of_Thrones"));
  add(credit);
     ComponentAnimation title =          hi.getToolbar().getTitleComponent().createStyleAnimation("Title", 200);
  hi.getAnimationManager().onTitleScrollAnimation(title);
  hi.show();
```

I was able to have the picture on the TitleBar but it was not animating.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a source UIID and destination UIID as we use them to reset the state. You used `Style` object manipulation which is problematic since it doesn't provide us with a way to "reset" the changes conveniently.

Comment: Pls can you help with a snippet code for better understanding. Thanks

Comment: Actually it's the same code only without the style manipulation, just place the style setting in the theme instead of the style. So there is no code to give